# Having issues to print page with images

Tags: html, printing

I am currently working in a ServiceNow feature to print a customized report I built with Jelly, but using basically HTML to display data, so nevermind the words ServiceNow and Jelly by now :).

I have a div, a table with tr and td, and inside one of the td's I have an image.

When I use the browser´s print method, the image doesn´t get rendered in the preview, neither in the printed document.

The strange part is, if I select the whole page and use the print again, then I have the image on the preview and on the printed document.

One thing I noticed is that the footer of the first trial I have something like this:

https://gfttest.service­now.com/pdf_generator_mock_ui_page.do

This is basically the URL of the current page I am seeing.

On the other hand, when I select the content and hit print, I have this information on the footer:

data:text/html;charset=utf­8,%3Ctable%20name%3D%22mainTable%22%20width%3D%22535%22%20style%3D%22font­size%3A%2013.333333015441...

This is my HTML in summary:

```
<html>
<div>
<table name="mainTable" width="535">
<tr>
<td colspan = "4" align="center">
<img id="report_logo" src="a465f5072187b1009dd0b3f4a30c63f1.iix"></img>
</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Any help would be trully appreciated.

Best regards,

Felipe

Answer (score 0):

In order to force the image to appear on the browser´s print preview and in the actual print page, you should have this style inside the  tag:

style="visibility: visible; display: block;"

With this you ensure the image you want to be rendered in the print area will work correctly.